# Set X to v? or Set X as v?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, academia

I'm writing an academic paper, and would like to say that the value of X is v using imperative form. (Specifically in the algorithm section. That's why I need to use imperative.)

Which among the followings is the best?

> Set X to v.
>
> Set X as v.
>
> Set X v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming, *set X to v* is a common idiom to mean changing the value of X to become v. Here's an example:

> The Set X to () block is a Motion block and a Stack block. The block changes its sprite's X position by the specified amount. [- Scratch Progrmaming Wiki](http://scratch.wikia.com/wiki/Set_X_to_%28%29_%28block%29)

The form *set X as v* is not as familiar to me, but it does occur and can be understood the same way. However, it can also be (and arguably, is *naturally*) understood in the opposite way. In the following example, X is used as the CAS variable (i.e. like *set CAS to x*):

> For Part 6, we will use X as the CAS variable. ...
>   To set X as the CAS variable ... [- Eddie's Math and Calculator Blog](http://edspi31415.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/rpl-programming-tutorial-part-6-hp.html)

The form *set X v* is ungrammatical. In scholarly work, it would require prior agreement / definition of the convention.

Here's another form you could try:

> Let X = v.

This form is unambiguous and is commonly used in mathematics and mathematical publications, and it is idiomatic among programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You could be a little more nuanced about selecting the way depending on how X is set using v and the data types involved. For example, if X and v were reference types, it makes more sense to me to use "to", and "as" if they were value types. e.g. "Set X (integer) as v (number 5)" and "Set X (interface) to v (an instantiated object)". "Set X v" on the other hand sounds a little incomplete.